# How to show that a function is differentiable even though its partial derivatives in origin don't exist

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

I have a function $ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
(x^2+y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}),  & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
0, & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$

and I need to show that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable, even though it doesn't have partial derivatives at the point $(0,0)$.

I have proven that the function is continuous in $(0,0)$, and even though I understand that the function may have discontinuity in parital derivatives, it can be differentiable, but I am unable to prove it.

Comment: If a function is differentiable at a point, that implies that the partial derivatives at that point exist.

Comment: If the partial derivatives doesn't exist in $0$, then your function won't be differentiable at $0$. The fact that is differentiable anywhere else is a consequence, of the fact that it's a quotient of differentiable function with the denominator $\neq 0$

Comment: Having partial derivatives is required as part of the definition of differentiability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have, taking the linear function with $a=b=0$,
$$
\frac{|f(x,y)-f(0,0)-(ax+by)|}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}
=\frac{(x^2+y^2)\left|\sin\frac1{x^2+y^2}\right|}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}
\leq(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}\to0
$$
when $(x,y)\to0$. So $f$ is differentiable at the origin and its derivative is the null linear map.

As mentioned in the comments, the partial derivatives at the origin do exist and are zero. For instance,
$$
\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}
=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{((0+h)^2+0^2)\sin\frac1{(0+h)^2+0^2}}h=h\,\sin\frac1{h^2}\to0.
$$